# Detect if site visit is new with js

Tags: javascript, html, web

I would like to check if a user who opens my website is new (type in url OR redirect through google) and then display a message.

But when the user browse through the site (subpages like about and so on) this message is not displayed.

But when the user closes the browser and visits (maybe a few mintues later) the website again, the message should be displayed again.

How can I implement something like this in JavaScript?

Comment: you should take a look at [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: firstImpression is a JavaScript micro-library that answers the question, "Has this visitor been here before?" - [firstImpression.js](https://github.com/robflaherty/firstImpression.js/tree/master)

Comment: You need some server-side features.
So you can not do it with only javascript...

Comment: @luk2302: Unless you're [targeting Europe](http://www.cookiechoices.org/)...

Comment: You can `sessionStorage` to remember a user for that session, and `localStorage` to remember a user until the user deletes the `localStorage`

Comment: What I forgot to mention: "But when the user closes the browser and visits (maybe a few mintues later) the website again, the message should be displayed again."

Comment: @BradChristie because Europe and IT just do not work well together :( having a banner on almost every site asking for cookie permission is just so f****** annoying :/

Comment: @luk2302: Agreed, but if you've ever run "Lightbeam" on firefox, I'm (dare I say it) in 100% support of this kind of thing. Too many websites track too much information (and yes, I'm glaring at you google). They start off with "we're doing it innocently", but then jump into "we just sold your last 5 years of browser history--thanks for that".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use cookies, `localStorage`, `sessionStorage` or the referrer info. Note that all of them have their own pros and cons and there is no 100% reliable way of detecting new visitors.

Using the [firstImpression.js](https://github.com/robflaherty/firstImpression.js) library that Nadav S mentioned is probably the easiest way.

To get the message to show up for users closing and reopening the site:

- unset your cookie / `localStorage` data [on unload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) or
- use a referrer info or `sessionStorage` based solution

See these MDN resources for more:

- [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)
- [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)
- [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)
- [referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer)

Slightly relevant as well: http://www.cookielaw.org/faq/

Comment: +1 and given the _"when the user closes the browser and visits the website again"_ requirement, it seems a session cookie fits the bill exactly.

Answer (score 3):

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer):

> Returns the URI of the page that linked to this page.

```
 string = document.referrer;
```

> The **value is an empty string if the user navigated to the page
>   directly** (not through a link, but, for example, via a bookmark). Since
>   this property returns only a string, it does not give you DOM access
>   to the referring page.

This means:

```
if (!document.referrer) {
    //Direct access
} else {
    var referer = document.referrer;
    //Request comes from referer
}
```

If you want to save this state, you need to take a look at [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).

Comment: @Nadavs. An off-domain referral can be assumed as a first-visit. Though referrals can be spoofed, I'm pro-this method (given European markets make cookies  sticky situation).

Comment: @BradChristie you're definitely right, but it doesn't solve the OP's question as per "type in url OR redirect through google". Christian, "Direct access" can still be a new visit. I understand both of you, still this isn't a precise method.

Comment: @NadavS.: if we're talking logistics, JS isn't the right method. Any of these solutions are going to fall under the "80%" margin. My belief is to avoid any kind of storage to detect it (esp. given a lot of people using private/incognito/whatever-you-call-it mode (and a lot of them disabling cookies/sessionStorage/localStorage APIs while in that mode)). That's even excluding the [dead horse I'm beating with regards to] Euro market and needing request consent.

Comment: @BradChristie well that's also true. I guess the best method is synthesizing IP+referrer+cookie. However that's for another question. BTW, everything can be spoofed... you can use a proxy. You can block JS. You can block cookies. You can spoof your referrer... Everything.

Answer (score 2):

Quite easily, you want session storage

```
var hasVisited = sessionStorage.getItem('washere');

if ( ! hasVisited ) {

    // do stuff
    alert('Welcome, stranger !');
    sessionStorage.setItem('washere', true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this by using cookies.

When the visitor first come to your page, you check if your cookie exist, if not show the message to them and then create the cookie for future pages.

Answer (score 0):

Using cookies is probably your best bet. They are super simple to use too. Just write

```
if(document.cookie = "HasVisited=true"){
   //whatever you want it to do if they have visited
}
else {
   document.cookie = "HasVisited=true"
   //that just saves to their browser that they have for future     reference
}
```